# Is it possible to save users details From AWS Cognito to DynamoDB without Triggers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to save users' details From AWS Cognito to DynamoDB without Triggers?
I want to save the user's data into Dynamodb from Cognito without the trigger function.

Comment: But what is wrong with the Lambda trigger? Its completely loosely coupled architecture and well recognized by AWS to use this design.Please provide more insights why not to use Lambda Triggers?

Comment: It was not triggering. It shows the InvalidLambdaResponseException error in the Cognito interface. Actually no errors in my lambda response. Also, I tried the default response from lambda. Still, it gets the error. So I decided to save users' data without post-confirmation trigger.